# How to fill the missing values for a replicated time series data?

Tags: r, merge, missing-data

I'm trying to filling a replicated time-series data with some missing values, and I have tried serveral methods, but none works.

The data should be like this:

```
Year   Var
2001   1
2002   2
2003   3
2001   4
2002   5  
2001   6
2003   7
```

What I want to get is:

```
Year   Var
2001   1
2002   2
2003   3
2001   4
2002   5 
2003   NA 
2001   6
2002   NA
2003   7
```

I have tried `merge()` by first building a dataframe which includes the whole sequence I need.

```
yearlabel <- data.frame(Year = rep(2001:2003, 3)    
df <- merge(df, yearlabel, all = T)
```

But the resutls had a number of `length(df)*length(yearlabel)` rows.

Also, I tried `cbind.fill` from the `rowr` package, it just add the `NAs` at the end of `df`. If I use

`Map(merge, df, yearlabel, by = 'Year', all = T)`,

it would return:

`Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column`

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with `complete`.  After creating a column 'grp' based on the occurence of 'min' value of "Year", use `complete` to expand the 'Year' from `min` to `max` with `seq`, `arrange` the rows based on 'grp' and remove the 'grp' column

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate(grp = cumsum(lag(Year  > lead(Year, default = 
                      last(Year)),default = TRUE))) %>%
   # or in this case, it can be simplified
   #mutate(grp = cumsum(Year == min(Year))) %>%
   complete(Year = min(Year):max(Year), grp) %>%
   arrange(grp) %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#   Year   Var
#  <int> <int>
#1  2001     1
#2  2002     2
#3  2003     3
#4  2001     4
#5  2002     5
#6  2003    NA
#7  2001     6
#8  2002    NA
#9  2003     7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2001L, 2002L, 2001L, 
 2003L), Var = 1:7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
  ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, akun. But I found some problems when the minimum year was missing. I have extended the orginal year range of my data to fix the problem. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @YannZhang. If there is no pattern, it becomes difficult.  Here, I assume the data is ordered in ascending.  Whenever,  there is a reversal of order, the created 'grp' will increment by 1.